# How to select date containing max hour value in R?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, group-by

I have the following dataset

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("12-01-2020", "12-01-2020", "12-01-2020", "12-02-2020", "12-02-2020", "12-02-2020", "12-03-2020", "12-03-2020", "12-03-2020"), hour = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), volume = c(28, 4, 12, 16, 33, 72, 55, 24, 65))
```

I am using the following technique to obtain the date with max volume

```
max_day <- df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(total_volume = sum(volume)) %>%
  slice(which.max(total_volume)) %>%
  select(Date)
```

When I do this, I am returned "12-03-2020" as the 3 days added together have the highest value.

I am trying to do the same thing but with a slight variation. I want to obtain the date with max hour. Right now I was trying something like above but it doesnt work.

```
max_hour <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, hour) %>%
  summarise(total_volume = sum(volume)) %>%
  slice(which.max(total_volume)) %>%
  select(Date)
```

I want have this return "12-02-2020" as that contains the highest hour = 72.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you group by Date and hour, and then the summarize step removes the last grouping level (hour), while keeping the prior grouping level(s) (Date). So unless you `ungroup() %>%`, or use `summarize(... , .groups = "drop") %>%`, the data is still grouped by Date at that stage, and you will get the max volume hour for each day instead of overall.

```
max_hour <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, hour) %>%
  summarise(total_volume = sum(volume)) %>%  # either add `.groups = "drop")` here,
  ungroup() %>%                              # or use this line  
  slice_max(total_volume)


# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Date        hour total_volume
  <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1 12-02-2020     3           72
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This works. But why does summarise remove the last grouping level?

Comment: See the help for `?dplyr::summarise` or at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html.  "When .groups is not specified, it is chosen based on the number of rows of the results:    - If all the results have 1 row, you get "drop_last".    - If the number of rows varies, you get "keep"."    I presume the function was designed to work that way because in some use cases it is useful to aggregate at multiple levels and you might want some of the grouping to stay in place after each step.